# node.js: downloading many images from urls: timeout as too many symultanous downloads

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, download

I have code that downloads images from given URLs. It loops through products in database and for each product calls Image download.

However, everything seems to happen asyncrhonously and if there are too many URLs (images to download) process stops with TIMEOUT. This is logicall as there are about 3000 images to download.

Can you give me some suggestions how to improve the code so that it downloads for instance only "10" images and do not start downloading for next images while previous "10" not finished? 
I am not used to node.js async functionality yet.

```
// download file
var download = function (uri, filename, callback) {
    request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {
        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))
            .on('error', () => {
                console.log('Err');
            })
            .on('close', callback);
    })

};

// main code - looping through products in DB and upload file for each product (about 3000 products)

knex("products").select("products.id as id", "products.img as img", "products.code as code")       
    .mapSeries(function (product) {
            var imgName = 'imgs/' + product.code.toString() + ".png";
            download(product.img, imgName, function () {
                knex("products").where("id", product.id).update("img_path", imgName).then(() => {

                });
            });
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        // console.log('done');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use async.eachOfLimit in order to proceed X async action by batch of Y elements :

```
var async = require("async");

// products retrieved from bdd
var products = [{img: "http://www.google.fr/a", code:"yolo", id:1}, {img: "https://www.google.fr/b", code:"yolo2", id:2}];

async.eachOfLimit(products, 10, function(currentproduct, key, ecb){

    // function called for each products
     var imgName = 'imgs/' + currentproduct.code.toString() + ".png"; 
    download(currentproduct.img, imgName, function () {
                knex("products").where("id", currentproduct.id).update("img_path", imgName).then(() => {
                  // call next
                  ecb(null);
                });
            });

}, function(err){

   // final callback when all products has been proceed
   if(err)
   {
     // do stg
   }
   else
   {
     console.log("yeah");
   }
})
```

Comment: But ow to form this products array if I have actually 3000 products in table and all are retrieved by knex query?

Comment: with knex replaces .mapSeries(product) by  .then(function(products), this will return all the product instead of applying function on all result

Answer (score 2):

We have these async function with **limit** for instance

```
mapLimit(coll, limit(number), iteratee, callback)


async.mapLimit(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.stat, function(err, results) {
    // results is now an array of stats for each file
});
```

or

```
eachLimit(coll, limit(number), iteratee, callback)
```

so this will solve your requirement as this will have only **limit** number of parallel calls at any given time

Comment: Will it continue to iterate after "limit" number will be done? For instance, if I have 1000 products that it will run for "10 in a row" and then continue?

Comment: yes @renathy this function is intended for this case, it will process the entire list before it stops or until an error occours